# DRF Can't get data for restricted URLs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using simple_JWT and I have a view that requires logged-in users.
When I try to send a request (tested with postman, curl, ...) I get 'Authentication credentials were not provided'.

---

views.py :

```
class CurrencyDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = CurrencyDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

settings.py :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ],
}
```

Comment: Are you sending a suitable JWT token with those requests? That sounds like you aren't.

Comment: I copied the token, so I guess it's correct (I even regenerated with refresh view and tried again)

Comment: How are you sending the token? Which header are you sending and in what format?

Comment: I'm using postman, since there is no Bearer for authorization type I use 'No Auth' and instead use headers like this: "Authorization" (this is the key) "JWT <token>" (this is the value). And I don't know  what do you mean by format (I changed nothing else)

Comment: You format the Authorization header like this `JWT <token>`? You should use `Bearer <token>`

Comment: after changing that I get this error: {"detail":"Given token not valid for any token type","code":"token_not_valid","messages":[{"token_class":"AccessToken","token_type":"access","message":"Token is invalid or expired"}]}

Comment: @KuroshGhanizadeh generate a new one and try again? By default the token will only be valid for 5 minutes

Comment: I then refreshed the token and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a recent token and make sure you are adding `Authorization` in the header with a value `JWT {{your_token}}`

Do not skip the space in between.